# Disable screen blur on fast user switching in Yosemite

Tags: macos, customization, fast-user-switching

Anyone aware of a way to customize the appearance of the screen during fast user switching? I'd like to disable the background blur to make it look more like it did in Mavericks.

Comment: cmd-opt-ctrl-B should work

Comment: dupe:http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/153111/remove-background-blur-effect-on-yosemite-login-screen

Answer (score 10):

Yes, you can change the blurred background image on the login screen in Yosemite.

In root /Library/Caches (make sure you're not in the user ~/Library) you will find a file called: com.apple.desktop.admin.png. This is the blurred image that was created when you set your Desktop wallpaper.

Replace this file with any image you would like on your login page. Make sure to keep the permissions the same as the original file.

Hat Tip to Bobby T from Apple Support Communities: https://discussions.apple.com/message/26879262#26879262

Cheryl

Comment: I've overwritten that file, got the permissions set but it still uses the blurry image on the lock screen and the login screen is just completely orange

Comment: This does not work. Whatever image you put there, it will blur it and gray it when it appears on the login screen.

Comment: This is correct. It will still be blurred. If you want to remove the blurring follow the thread downstream. I haven't tried it yet, so can't say if it works or not. The only other option, as also mentioned downstream is to downgrade back to Mavericks.

Comment: @jimrandomh Mine's not blurred, but it's darker for sure.

Answer (score 2):

oh yes ..you can change the login screen as well.. The howto provided in this link. The only 1 thing not mentioned there is to make sure that the 'permission' of the png file is set to be able to be read by the user. http://www.tekrevue.com/tip/custom-login-screen-wallpaper-os-x-yosemite/

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Answer (score 2):

Go to /Library/Caches, and modify the `com.apple.desktop.admin.png` file. That contains an image for your login screen in Fast-User-Switching.

By default, the image looks like a place in Yosemite. Replace the image with an image of your choice that's not blurred.

This requires Admin privileges, though. Also, make sure you're not in ~/Library/Caches, you have to be in (Root)/Library/Caches. This image might be hidden.

Comment: modify it to what? Please edit your answer to provide full instructions.

Comment: An image you want, thet's not blurred.

Answer (score -1):

To disable blurring, please read this tip http://www.mcelhearn.com/yosemite-tip-how-to-turn-off-the-annoying-translucency/

Comment: Alas this only changes the blurring of windows - not the login screen background. Thanks though :)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.