# Remove blur effect from lock screen on High Sierra

Tags: mac, macos, multitasking, wallpaper, lockscreen

I'm on High Sierra 10.13.5. Following [these steps](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/155892/296180) to use my unblurred original wallpaper on the initial login screen of my Mac worked perfectly. Now I would like to do the same thing with the lock screen. While at work I have to lock the screen every time I step away from my desk. But I've never liked that my wallpaper is blurred while on the lock screen. I searched and searched but I couldn't find any instructions for getting rid of the blur effect on the lock screen, only for the *login screen*, which, as I've said, I've already done successfully.

Does anyone know if it's possible to remove the blur effect from the lock screen wallpaper?

Answer (score 1):

I found this article online, and I hope this helps. I just saw someone who had their lock screen be un-blurred, and I started researching it. So, I saw this and created an account on StackExchange to post this. I hope this helps. I am also new to StackExchange, so if the answer could be changed for the better please let me know so I can change it.

[Here is the link](https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/29503/how-to-change-the-logon-background-in-os-x/)

If you’d rather your login screen not be blurred, you can do that too! I recommend first adding a custom image to your desktop so that there is an image in the `/Library/Caches` folder. Then, copy that image to your desktop by dragging it there.

[image: image 1]

We’ll use this image in a little bit. First, open whatever image you’d like to show up behind your login screen with Preview. Select the entire canvas (Command+A), then copy it (Command+C).

[image: image 2]

Next, head to your desktop and open the file you copied from `/Library/Caches`. Paste (Command+V) what you just copied.

[image: image 3]

You will need to move and resize what you’re pasting quite a bit in order to get everything just right. When you’re done, save the image (Command+S). Head back to your desktop, and drag your edited image to the `/Library/Caches` folder. You will be asked if you’d like to replace the file that’s there; click “Replace.”

[image: image 4]

You’ve now placed your custom background image. Go ahead and log out of your user account to see how it looks:

[image: image 5]

It worked! In my case, however, the white maple leaf is making it hard to read the white text used by macOS. To fix this, I found a different version of this image where the leaf is blue.

[image: image 6]

Much better! This version puts the darker part of the image behind the text, which makes it easier to read everything. You’ll probably have to experiment with this a little yourself, but to avoid problems favor dark images over light ones, and simple images over complex ones.

If you’re a Photoshop guru, you might prefer making an image yourself over messing around with Preview in this way. You can do that, but the image you create needs to meet specific criteria. It must be:

- A PNG file
- The same exact resolution as your primary display
- RGB, sRGB, or Adobe RGB color mode.
- 8bit colors
- Unlocked background layer
- Named “com.apple.desktop.admin.png”
  In our tests, even doing all these things can still be hit-or-miss, so we suggest using the Preview method. It’s just simpler.